# Boost asio shared_from_"multiple" this

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I have a wrapper class over boost ASIO TCP socket. The class takes a `weak_ptr` to the `Connection` - actual logic that uses the TCP socket. This so that I can make sure the `Connection` doesnt go away, while there is some pending async operation - say `async_read_some()`

```
template <typename Connection>
struct TCPClient : public enable_shared_from_this<TCPClient> {

 std::weak_ptr<Connection> cxn_;
 TCPClient (weak_ptr<Connection> cxn) : cxn_(cxn) {}

 void something ()
 {  
     // Give the handler to async_op
     auto cxn = cxn_.lock();
     if (!cxn) return;

     some_asio_async_op( [cxn = std::move(cxn)] ()
                        {
                            // do some stuff
                            cxn->notify();
                         });
}


struct MyCxn : public enable_shared_from_this<MyCxn> {

  shared_ptr<TCPClient<MyCxn>> _channel;

  setConnection ()
  {
       _channel = make_shared<TCPClient<MyCxn>>(shared_from_this())
  }

  start()
  {
      setConnection();
      something();
  }
}
```

The obvious problem is that while the connection is preserved, the `TCPClient` class itself is not preserved if the `_channel` is deleted before `MyCxn`.

The fix is to do this in the `TCPClient` class

```
 // Give the handler to async_op
 some_async_op( [self = shared_from_this()] ()
               {
                  // do some stuff
                  auto cxn = cxn_.lock()
                  if (cxn)
                      cxn->notify();
               });
```

But copying 2 `shared_ptrs` for every read/write looks like too much. Is this the only way? Or is there a efficient way of doing it? Currently the lifetime of the `MyCxn` and `_channel` is both same and so I can make do with only preserving `cxn`. But there could be a case where the channel should reset.

Comment: who owns what? Does a connection own a client or vice verse?

Comment: ^ What @RichardHodges said. Because you may be able to use the "aliasing constructor" of std::shared_ptr ([ad. 8](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr))

Comment: So the connection owns the client. Client is a shared_ptr member of connection.

Comment: So I tried this, but I couldnt figure out a way to make this work. I think it will work neatly only if we have to give a member as a shared pointer externally. Not in my specific case.

Comment: @sehe So I guess if both the client and connection can be deleted independently, then the only option is to copy both the shared_ptrs every async operation?

Comment: @user361190 you can usually avoid having two lifetimes. If the lifetime of the client is limited by the connection, then perhaps the socket and client should live in the same object? The connection would be kept alive by shared_ptr in outstanding async read/write operations. disconnecting or shutting down the socket will cause these ops to fail, in which case you would not re-initiate a read.

Comment: @Richard Hodges hmm that is what I am going for now - basically make the lifetime of `MyCxn == TCPClient` (in the code in qn). The socket is part of client so they live in same object. When the socket is closed, ASIO will call all pending async handlers with error to free up all resourses. But if the `TCPClient` is deleted the call will come to destructed  class. So I cannot reset (read delete, create) the `TCPClient` structure, as only `MyCxn` is kept alive.

Comment: @user361190 boost solves this internally by separating lifetimes of handle and implementation.